# Exporting a file in .geojson format without T inside the date

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, python-datetime

I am trying to export a geodataframe in .geojson format. Before exporting, I print the geodataframe in the terminal and the dates appear as I wish:

[image]

After writing the line to export the file in .geojson format

`predicted_events.to_file("predicted_events.geojson", driver='GeoJSON')`,

I print from the terminal and a T appears in the date column:

[image]

When I export in .csv format, the T does not appear either.

Comment: maybe convert dates to strings before exporting

Comment: [Please do not upload images of data/code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

It is correctly encoding the data type of the column.  Convert from date to string and then the *GEOJSON* contains what you require.

```
import shapely.wkt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from pathlib import Path

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[shapely.wkt.loads(p) for p in ['POINT (6.493069295913722 55.7355541882027)',
       'POINT (15.43828764139886 46.30211698572747)',
       'POINT (12.60117419209274 43.69100105361232)',
       'POINT (6.876712332538435 40.26684145530385)']], data={"date":pd.date_range("1-jan-2021",periods=4)})

f = Path.cwd().joinpath("predicted_events.geojson")
gdf.to_file(f, driver='GeoJSON')

with open(f) as fh:
    text = fh.read()
    print(text)

gdf["date"] = gdf["date"].astype(str)
gdf.to_file(f, driver='GeoJSON')
with open(f) as fh:
    text = fh.read()
    print(text)
```

#### output

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "date": "2021-01-01T00:00:00" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 6.493069295913722, 55.735554188202698 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "date": "2021-01-02T00:00:00" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 15.43828764139886, 46.302116985727473 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "date": "2021-01-03T00:00:00" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.60117419209274, 43.691001053612318 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "date": "2021-01-04T00:00:00" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 6.876712332538435, 40.266841455303847 ] } }
]
}

{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "date": "2021-01-01" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 6.493069295913722, 55.735554188202698 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "date": "2021-01-02" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 15.43828764139886, 46.302116985727473 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "date": "2021-01-03" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.60117419209274, 43.691001053612318 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "date": "2021-01-04" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 6.876712332538435, 40.266841455303847 ] } }
]
}
```